# Regroup, summarise and combine variables

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've been breaking my head to understand how to do this but so far I couldn't find an easy solution.
I have the following dataset:

```
Itin   Origin  Destination  Passengers
1      A       B            1
1      B       C            1
2      A       B            3
3      E       B            10
4      A       C            2
5      E       B            4
```

What I'm trying to do is based on the `Itin` variable, to create a path variable, while keeping the passengers variable.
The easiest way of understanding this is by seeing it as taking a normal flight with a scale somewhere. For example in `Itin = 1` one passenger goes from A to B to C. The only thing that has to be kept is the Origin `A` Destination `B`, destination `C` and passengers as it is, which is equal to 1. Just like on the example below.

```
Path    Passengers
A-B-C   1
A-B     3
E-B     10
A-C     2
E-B     4
```

I've tried several options with group_by with dplyr, as it is often quicker than the base options, but I couldn't really get the result as on the second example with a new variable Path. I thought as well to use tidyr but I'm not really sure how it could help here.
Any idea on how to do this?

Edit: As for the Path variable, it doesn't really matter if ends up as `A-B-C`, or `A,B,C` or `A B C` as I will only look at the syntax.

Comment: Can you assume the dataset is sorted?  i.e., the first leg of the flight is the first row for that particular itinerary.

Comment: @thc yes it is sorted indeed as I did it already before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** A faster solution using `data.table`

```
df1<-read.table(text="Itin   Origin  Destination  Passengers
1      A       B            1
1      B       C            1
2      A       B            3
3      E       B            10
4      A       C            2
5      E       B            4",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(data.table)
DT <-data.table(df1)
DT[,.(Passengers, Path = paste(Origin[1],paste(Destination, collapse = " "),
                               collapse = " ")), by=Itin]

   Itin Passengers  Path
1:    1          1 A B C
2:    1          1 A B C
3:    2          3   A B
4:    3         10   E B
5:    4          2   A C
6:    5          4   E B
```

Here's my orignal solution with `dplyr`:

```
df1<-read.table(text="Itin   Origin  Destination  Passengers
1      A       B            1
1      B       C            1
2      A       B            3
3      E       B            10
4      A       C            2
5      E       B            4",header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
group_by(Itin) %>%
summarise(Passengers=max(Passengers),
          Path = paste(Origin[1],paste(Destination, collapse = " "),
                                collapse = " "))

# A tibble: 5 × 3
   Itin Passengers  Path
  <int>      <int> <chr>
1     1          1 A B C
2     2          3   A B
3     3         10   E B
4     4          2   A C
5     5          4   E B
```

Comment: Thanks. It does work indeed. I wonder though if it's possible to speed it up as for 9.000.000 observations it takes about 4 minutes. I've been trying it with unite() from tidyr, but I don't think it's a solution.
I'm also not sure if the time it takes is due to the paste() or to something else.

Comment: @FilipeTeixeira I added a `data.table` solution, which should be much faster. If the `dplyr` solution took 4 minutes on your real life data set, I believe, the `data.table` solution should take about 30 seconds. Tell me how long it takes, I'm curious.

Comment: Works perfectly. Running the `data.table` option takes ~120 seconds instead of 240, which is considerable as in the end these 9.000.000 observations are only Q1 for one year and I have 10 years to look at. Thank you. You saved me a lot of time with a really simple solution :).

Answer (score 0):

Reading data:

```
read.table(textConnection("Itin   Origin  Destination  Passengers
1      A       B            1
1      B       C            1
2      A       B            3
3      E       B            10
4      A       C            2
5      E       B            4"), header=T, stringsAsFactors=F) -> df
```

Using base R in this case:

```
Path <- lapply(unique(df$Itin), function(it) {
    x <- subset(df, Itin==it)
    c(x$Origin[1], x$Destination)
})
new_df <- unique(df[,c("Itin", "Passengers")]) 
new_df$Path <- Path

> new_df
  Itin Passengers    Path
1    1          1 A, B, C
3    2          3    A, B
4    3         10    E, B
5    4          2    A, C
6    5          4    E, B
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately as I have about 9.000.000 observations this option is too slow. I ran the code and after 15 minutes it wasn't over yet. That's why I was more going for a Dplyr option which tends to be faster.